# Change type / len of a user defined column in My SQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, query-string

I am using a MySQL query in Workbench that uses group_concat() to group multiple string values.

```
select group_concat(iba.name, '   ' separator "--") as Entity_Business_Activity 
from entity_business_activities ent_eba
left join entities ent on ent.entity_id = ent_eba.entity_id # for entity Business Activity
left join industries ent_ind on ent_eba.industry_id = ent_ind.industry_id # Needs a group concat
left join industry_business_activities iba on ent_eba.industry_business_activity_id = iba.industry_business_activity_id #(need to be group concat)
where ent.entity_id = 600
group by ent.entity_id;
```

Here is a sample Output.
[image]

The issue that I am facing here is the grouped string values are too long, sometimes increasing 2000 characters. But only 1024 characters are extracted and the rest skipped.

Is there any way that I can set the Type of this Custom Column or any possibility to increase the character length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 10000;
```